# When should I call [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:] to ensure that .xib file has immediate access to preferences?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I need to register default preference values, which are then used by the interface immediately upon launching to set checkbox states, etc.

I register the defaults in the app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{ 
    NSLog(@"Did finish launching");
    NSDictionary *defaultPrefs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isEnabled"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultPrefs];
}
```

then, in an object that's created via the MainMenu.xib file, I want to use the default values:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"Awake from nib");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [self.checkbox setState:([defaults boolForKey:@"isEnabled"] ? NSOnState : NSOffState)];
}
```

But these are called in the wrong order!

```
> Awake from nib
> Did finish launching
// Preference == `nil` or `0`, not the default value I set.
```

Thus the default prefs are not set when I want to use them.

Where should I `registerDefaults:` so that the default prefs can be used to set up the .xib file interface objects?

Am I using the wrong delegate methods? `applicationDidFinishLaunching` / `awakeFromNib` ? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

I normally register defaults in the [`+initialize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize) class method of the controller object in which they'll be used. `+initialize` is one of the earliest methods that is called in the lifetime of an object, so it assures that they are registered as early as possible.

```
+ (void)initialize {
     NSDictionary *defaultPrefs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isEnabled"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultPrefs];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Register the defaults in the `init` method of your app delegate class. This will ensure they are registered first.

Comment: Assuming your app delegate is not instantiated within the MainMenu nib. If it is, then that's not before the nib is loaded.